# Submit a file without using submit button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a project where in I have a form with a file...
How can I submit the form to a controller action without using the submit button just a plain button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. Start uploading of file on selection of file event callback.
2. Start uploading of file on click on a html element
3. Upload the obvious way

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve what you want. Here is the basics taken from [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

In your jQuery:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  //Do stuff, then submit
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using plain javascript):

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Just a Button" onclick="submitForm()">
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitForm() {
    document.myForm.submit();
 }
</script>
```